# Windows 10 x86 on uefix64 system (via network) error at the end of the installtion

Tags: windows, 64-bit, uefi, windows-installation, windows-installer

I created a TFTP boot server (Tiny PXE Server on Windows Server 2019).
I create 3 different boot situation: Legacy mode, EFI 32, EFI 64

When using Legacy mode, I'm able to boot WinPEx32 or WinPEx64 to install Windows x86 or x64.
When usgin EFI 32, I'm able to install only Windows x86.
When usgin EFI 64, I'm able to install only Windows x64.

When I boot via EFI 64 and I try to install Windows x86, I can start the setup but at the end of it, the installation give me an error:
*"Setup cannot continue due to a corrupted installation file. Contact the vendor of your Windows installation disc or your system administration assistance."*

I'm using the boot.wim image on the ISO from Microsoft.
In the cbs.log I can read:

```
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   PID=2040 TID=1088 Scratch directory set to 'X:\windows\TEMP\'. - CDISMManager::put_ScratchDir
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   PID=2040 TID=1088 DismCore.dll version: 10.0.18362.1 - CDISMManager::FinalConstruct
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   PID=2040 TID=1088 Scratch directory set to 'E:\$WINDOWS.~LS\PackageTemp\90009d0b-07d0-47e6-8728-43765864d00e'. - CDISMManager::put_ScratchDir
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   Initialized Panther logging at E:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\cbs.log
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   PID=2040 TID=1088 Successfully loaded the ImageSession at "X:\sources" - CDISMManager::LoadLocalImageSession
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   Initialized Panther logging at E:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\cbs.log
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2040 TID=1088 Found and Initialized the DISM Logger. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_InitializeLogger
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2040 TID=1088 Failed to get and initialize the PE Provider.  Continuing by assuming that it is not a WinPE image. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2040 TID=1088 Finished initializing the Provider Map. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnConnect
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   Initialized Panther logging at E:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\cbs.log
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Manager: PID=2040 TID=1088 Successfully created the local image session and provider store. - CDISMManager::CreateLocalImageSession
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: 
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: <----- Starting Dism.exe session ----->
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: 
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Host machine information: OS Version=10.0.17134, Running architecture=amd64, Number of processors=2
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Dism.exe version: 10.0.18362.1
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Executing command line: X:\sources\dism.exe  /logpath:E:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\cbs.log /scratchdir:E:\$WINDOWS.~LS\PackageTemp\90009d0b-07d0-47e6-8728-43765864d00e /image:E:\ /is-serviceable
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2040 TID=1088 Getting the collection of providers from a local provider store type. - CDISMProviderStore::GetProviderCollection
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2040 TID=1088 Connecting to the provider located at X:\sources\FolderProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Warning               DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2040 TID=1088 Failed to load the provider: X:\sources\SiloedPackageProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e)
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Warning               DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2040 TID=1088 Failed to load the provider: X:\sources\FfuProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e)
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2040 TID=1088 Connecting to the provider located at X:\sources\WimProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2040 TID=1088 Connecting to the provider located at X:\sources\VHDProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2040 TID=1088 Connecting to the provider located at X:\sources\ImagingProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Warning               DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2040 TID=1088 Failed to load the provider: X:\sources\MetaDeployProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e)
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Got the collection of providers. Now enumerating them to build the command table.
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: DISM Log Provider
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: FolderManager
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: WimManager
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: WimManager.
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: VHDManager
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Attempting to add the commands from provider: GenericImagingManager
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Succesfully registered commands for the provider: GenericImagingManager.
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2040 TID=1088 Getting the collection of providers from a local provider store type. - CDISMProviderStore::GetProviderCollection
[2040] [0x80070002] FIOReadFileIntoBuffer:(1381): The system cannot find the file specified.
[2040] [0xc142011c] UnmarshallImageHandleFromDirectory:(641)
[2040] [0xc142011c] WIMGetMountedImageHandle:(2897)
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM WIM Provider: PID=2040 TID=1088 [E:\] is not a WIM mount point. - CWimMountedImageInfo::Initialize
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM VHD Provider: PID=2040 TID=1088 [E:\] is not recognized by the DISM VHD provider. - CVhdImage::Initialize
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Warning               DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2040 TID=1088 Failed to retrieve the Provider Instance. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x80004005)
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM VHD Provider: PID=2040 TID=1088 [E:\] is not recognized by the DISM VHD provider. - CVhdImage::Initialize
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Imaging Provider: PID=2040 TID=1088 The provider VHDManager does not support CreateDismImage on E:\ - CGenericImagingManager::CreateDismImage
[2040] [0x80070002] FIOReadFileIntoBuffer:(1381): The system cannot find the file specified.
[2040] [0xc142011c] UnmarshallImageHandleFromDirectory:(641)
[2040] [0xc142011c] WIMGetMountedImageHandle:(2897)
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM WIM Provider: PID=2040 TID=1088 [E:\] is not a WIM mount point. - CWimMountedImageInfo::Initialize
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Imaging Provider: PID=2040 TID=1088 The provider WimManager does not support CreateDismImage on E:\ - CGenericImagingManager::CreateDismImage
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Imaging Provider: PID=2040 TID=1088 No imaging provider supported CreateDismImage for this path - CGenericImagingManager::CreateDismImage
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Manager: PID=2040 TID=1088 physical location path: E:\ - CDISMManager::CreateImageSession
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Manager: PID=2040 TID=1088 Event name for current DISM session is Global\__?_Volume{db0c7b4f-2c76-4e94-aa1c-f9b5289ac971}__1679079405_65536_34911 - CDISMManager::CheckSessionAndLock
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Manager: PID=2040 TID=1088 Create session event 0x204 for current DISM session and event name is Global\__?_Volume{db0c7b4f-2c76-4e94-aa1c-f9b5289ac971}__1679079405_65536_34911  - CDISMManager::CheckSessionAndLock
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Error                 DISM   DISM Manager: PID=2040 TID=1088 Unable to complete the operation. Servicing an x86 based image from an x64 based host that does not support WOW64 is not supported. Try the operation again from a supported host environment. - CDISMManager::CreateImageSessionFromLocation(hr:0x800700c1)
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Error                 DISM   DISM.EXE: Could not load the image session. HRESULT=800700C1
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Image session has been closed. Reboot required=no.
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: 
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: <----- Ending Dism.exe session ----->
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: 
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2040 TID=1088 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2040 TID=1088 Disconnecting Provider: FolderManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2040 TID=1088 Disconnecting Provider: WimManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2040 TID=1088 Disconnecting Provider: VHDManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2040 TID=1088 Disconnecting Provider: GenericImagingManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2020-05-02 01:38:35, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=2040 TID=1088 Releasing the local reference to DISMLogger.  Stop logging. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
```

When I boot via EFI 32 and I try to install Windows x64 it finish and reboot, but seems that it doesn't write on the bootloader, so Windows 10 cannot boot from the hard disk.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you not simply use the correct method (bit strength) as you know that works.

Comment: Because I need to install x86 Operating System on EFI 64 Bios PC

Comment: I don't think that will work. Why do you need to do it this way?